# Using Github Desktop to put firebase functions on Github

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, github-for-windows

Normally when I upload a project to Github I enable version control for the project, but I have created a firebase functions project and it seems like there is no way in visual studio code to enable version control, so how do I upload this project to Github?

Answer (score 0):

After rereading your title I now realize that you wanted to do this from github desktop. Which I am not familiar with. here is a guide from github. [Creating your first repository using GitHub Desktop](https://help.github.com/en/desktop/getting-started-with-github-desktop/creating-your-first-repository-using-github-desktop)

#### Here is how i suggest you do it

When you create a github project from github.com there is an option to create an empty repository without a readme(this is the default). It gives you instruction on how to add a project from your terminal

```sh
echo "# test" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:wbedu/test.git
git push -u origin master
```